# Django Type Error - render to string got multiple values for keyword argument context_instance

Tags: django, render, typeerror

I'm new in django and I collect all the static and templates from the admin site to customize. Now I'm trying to render a queryset to the change_list.html from the admin site. 
**view.py**

```
def person_list(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        qs = Person.objects.all()
        return render(request, 'admin/change_list.html', {'app_label': 'clients'}, {'results_list':qs})
   else:
       return render(request, 'admin/change_list.html')
```

And I'm getting this type error:

```
render_to_string() got multiple values for keyword argument 'context_instance'
```

Here is the full traceback:

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/clients/persons/

Django Version: 1.5.1
Python Version: 2.7.4
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'equipment',
 'workers',
 'clients',
 'rents',
 'bills',
 'pays')
Installed Middleware:
('django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  115.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/home/facundo/dev/BLPServicios/blpservicios/clients/views.py" in persona_list
  9.         return render(request, 'admin/change_list.html', {'app_label': 'clients'},     {'results_list':qs})
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/shortcuts/__init__.py" in render
  53.     return HttpResponse(loader.render_to_string(*args, **kwargs),

Exception Type: TypeError at /clients/persons/
Exception Value: render_to_string() got multiple values for keyword argument 'context_instance'
```

Can you help me solve this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you are using the admin module to do something it can't... what are you trying to do?

i guess you'd better try to do it without the admin. often customizing it is more painful than implementing the code yourself, because of its complexity!

in particular, the `{% result_list cl %}` tag you see in the admin tamplate change_list.html (line 91) is not a template varible (that you are trying to pass in the context) but a template custom tag! whatever you want to do, this is the wrong path ;)

Comment: I want to use the admin templates and all the statics of the admin site. Show different list from the same model, list somes joins query results, reorder fields of add forms

Comment: the django admin module is not made to do this. you could manage to do it, but it's probably going to be a giant hack, less elegant and less mantainable than building a django app yourself.

Comment: Thanks you very much! I'll make my own templates

Answer (score 2):

Try send values in one dictionary

```
{'app_label': 'clients', 'results_list':qs}
```

Comment: I also try it but I get NoReverseMatch error `Reverse for 'app_list' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{u'app_label': ''}' not found.`

Comment: So I try to create a template overriding `{% block result_list %}` of the change_list.html that iterate the query set `{% extends "admin/change_list.html" %}{% block result_list %}{% for p in result_list %}{{ p }}{% endfor %}{% endblock %}`