# Highly customized admin - Create an app or hack the source code?

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I have been facing a big challenge with django since I was assigned the task to rebuild the admin page of our platform. I started unsure of what to do and now that I am half way on, I am even more unsure.

Here is my question:

## If I want to build a highly customized admin, should I do a giant hack on the source code or create a new app?

## 1) Giant Hack

That is how I started and got stuck. A couple of problems appeared on the way, for instance:

1. I had to extend the AdminSite and override every view I wanted to change
2. Django's admin is very modular (I mean, very very modular) and a screen might be the sum of tons of other templates
3. Creating a simple navbar is a pain in the ass (at least it has been for a newbie like me). This is due to the fact that `app_list` (the variable that contains the mapped models to show in admin's first page) not being accessible when other templates rather than base.html are injected. Thus, I would have to create a context processor, replace every `TemplateResponse()` by `render()` (technically, since I tried to do it and it didn't work as well)

The problems go on and on. Given my lack of experience with django, I might be doing crap, but it does feel like I am on the wrong way.

[this guy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18059342/django-type-error-render-to-string-got-multiple-values-for-keyword-argument-co) motivated me to post this.

## 2) Building a brand new app

Of course it will take a little while to implement this, but it seems like a robust and maintainable way of getting it done. One of the points is that I will need to give the same flexibility as the default admin site gives when adding models and promptly having their cruds and tables (I am not really sure how to accomplish this behavior).

I am pretty new to django and any guidelines will be highly appreciated. Give me your thoughts on how to make it.

Comment: What do you mean with "a highly customized admin"? There're lots of Django apps for customizing Django admin, its theme, views and forms. Check out djangopackages.com by and search for "admin" or "admin styling". Also, the anwser you've linked is 2 years old: Django community has been doing a lot a work to enable us to customize it ways two years ago were not possible then. So, it would be nice if you define better what you're trying to achieve. Maybe you can enumerate and explain three or four big issues you have.

Comment: Well, one of the problems with existing django packages is: they offer me styles, and I need to follow my own. At first glance, after figuring out that I was going to subclass AdminSite (where and how I should do it), I started rebuilding the views. It is a complete pain. The point where I got stuck now is how to build a navbar using app_list since it belongs to base.html's view's context. While striving to a create context processor to hold app_list and swapping existing TemplateResponse for render(), I noticed it was harder than it should be. Ps. Project uses django 1.6.x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to overwrite admin views. The easiest way is to overwrite the templates and add your own css & javascripts.

I have added my own navbar, sidebars and bottom. It is really easy if you overwrite the admin base templates.

If needed you can provide custom data to the template by using own templatetags.

Comment: yep, the solution was to add template tags! Thanks Kari-Antii